# Python Selenium: Login automation, Layer Problem?

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I am using Python Selenium to Login through a Webpage, i have done that before, my code was working pretty fine in that case:

```
driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("user")
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit' and @value='Login / Register']").click()
```

But now, as I would like to do that again, it doesnt work anymore. I have tried some variations but none of them have worked for me, I also tried to access through layers, which I have seen in some older cases:

```
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "loginmask")))
driver.find_element_by_id("yourName").send_keys('username')
.....
```

I also tried something like that:

```
frame = driver.find_element_by_id("mainBody")
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
driver.find_element_by_id("yourName").send_keys('username')
```

But somehow the find_element_by_id function isnt working for me, but the id is the only thing I can search for in that case.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jiyt3.png)

this image of the login page might be helpful, as you can see the layers i might have to bypass. Maybe you can help me how to get the Element 'yourName'

Better Picture of HTML Body:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo8NK.png)
HTML Body:

```
<body id="mainBody" style="visibility: visible;">
    <div id="treeLeft" style="height: 882px;">
        <img id="logoLeft" src="img/ax_01.png" alt="">
        <div id="buttonAreaLeft">
            <img id="btnLogout" src="img/logoff.gif" title="logout" alt="" style="float:right">
            <img id="btnHome" src="img/home.gif" title="startpage" alt="" style="float:left">
            <br clear="all">
        </div>
        <div id="myMenuAccordion"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainLayer" style="left: 230px; width: 1125px; height: 860px; top: 12px;"><h1>AX Controller WEB-Interface</h1>
<div id="loginLayer" style="position:absolute;top:120px;left:120px;">
    <h1>PLEASE LOGIN</h1>
    <div class="hspacer5"></div>
    <div class="hspacer5"></div>
    <div id="loginmask" class="form">
        <form method="post" action="index.php" onsubmit="venue.login();return false;">
        <span class="label block">Your Name:</span><input type="text" id="yourName" maxlength="20" style="width:110px;" autocomplete="off"><br>
        <div class="hspacer5"></div>
        <span class="label block">Password:</span><input type="password" id="authCode" maxlength="20" style="width:110px;" autocomplete="off"><br>
        <div class="hspacer5"></div>
        <span class="label block">&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" id="btnLogin" value="login" style="width:112px;padding:1px 0px;">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any [iframe] tag so you don't need to switch frame. Just add some explicit waiting and using find_element_by_id is enough.Just using [driver.find_element_by_id("yourName").send_keys('username')]

Comment: try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'yourName')))
    print("Page is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!") i tried that one, gave it a delay of 10 sek (the webside did load) but no chance

Comment: can you send me the url link to your website so i can look deeper inside html body.

Comment: You can only access the webpage while in the same network which is why i cant give you the url. but i can edit the question and give you a better picture of the html body, thanks for you help btw!

Comment: Please provide code and not images.
If possible provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hope this is enough?